# WinForms MVP with BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a long Data Query running, the user needs to see the progress.

So I came across [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx), seemed easy so I tried implementing it into my application. With some testing it did not respond, so while researching I came across that you need to do it different when using the Model View Presenter design pattern. When researching I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12771758/7018581).

So I tried implementing it:

**IView**

```
    public interface IChecks : IView
{
    void getDataSets(DataSet ds);
    event EventHandler CheckActive;
    string sqlQuery { get; set; }
    int checkNumber { get; set; }
    void ShowProgress(int progressPercentage);
    bool isBusy { get; set; }
    event EventHandler StartTimeConsumingJob;
}
```

**View**

```
private void CheckButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Execute 5 checks, with an number given so the right DataGridViews get filled.
        if (Check1.Checked == true)
        {
            checkNumber = 1;
            sqlQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT e.[BUO] ,e.[Method] ,[EANLocationCode] ,[Customer] FROM [Navision].[dbo].[InventorySales] e WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT c.BUO, c.CustomerCode FROM Customers c WHERE c.BUO = e.BUO AND c.CustomerCode = CustomerNo) ORDER BY BUO, Method, LocationCode";
            StartTimeConsumingJob(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void getDataSets(DataSet ds)
    {
        if(checkNumber == 1)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            Check1Label.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
            Check1Label.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

**Presenter**

```
        private BackgroundWorker _bw;

    public ChecksPresenter(IChecks view) : base(view)
    {
        View.CheckActive += View_CheckActive;
        View.StartTimeConsumingJob += View_StartTimeConsumingJob;
        _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        _bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        _bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_bw_DoWork);
        _bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(_bw_ProgressChanged);
        _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(_bw_Completed);
    }

    void View_CheckActive(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        View.getDataSets(CheckModel.dt(View.sqlQuery));
    //This function returns database data.
    }

    public void View_StartTimeConsumingJob(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void _bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        View.isBusy = true;
        View.getDataSets(CheckModel.dt(View.sqlQuery));
    }

    private void _bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        View.ShowProgress(e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    private void _bw_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

*I left some things out, because I did try to let it work first.* It did not work and no respond, it only crashes when I press the button 2 times (but that makes sense because I did not implement the if else in the CheckButton_click event).

**My question:**

What am I missing that it does not respond? It is more like the actual database connection does not happen. It works without the background worker but I would like to have more clarity when the query's are performed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Practice for BackGroundWorker in WinForms using an MVP architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349380/best-practice-for-backgroundworker-in-winforms-using-an-mvp-architecture)

Comment: *Never* write an empty Completed event handler.  It is crucial to always check the e.Error property, it tells you whether the worker thread failed.  Sure it did, your view is not thread-safe.  Assigning the Text property reliably makes it bomb.  Assigning the DataSource property doesn't, that fails in a far nastier way but only once a week.  Completed is also useful to update the view with the worker results.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried it with the example I gave, after that I made it empty. Thanks for the tip but when I tested it I noticed no difference.